# How to make text fit inside button

Tags: css, angular

I have a button in Angular and the text inside of it changes, at times the text is longer than the button and so it continues off the side of it. I am trying to figure out a way to make the font-size smaller if the text is too large for the button without the use of a library or importing anything. Does anyone know of such a method?

Comment: I can already tell you set a fixed width for your button css. Remove that and it will adjust to text. No need to make font-size smaller

Comment: @EvikGhazarian Although that is true I want my button to stay the same length, the whole point is that when the text becomes too big the font size becomes smaller so you can see the entire text inside the same size button